# Gradle build takes a long time to complete in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-x86

I'm facing an issue in the android studio, whenever I create a new project the Gradle Build or Sync takes hours to get completed. I'll be using both emulator and device to run the app.

My system config - 
1 TB Hard Disk
16 GB Ram
64 bit Windows7 Professional

Can someone please explain me the reason for the same and also please let know how to improve the performance of the same.